# Populate Dropdown Menu in PHP from JSON

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON in a file `menu.txt`:

```
[{
"title":"About",
"url":"/about",
"nodes":[
    {"title":"Staff","url":"/about/staff"},
    {"title":"Location","url":"/about/location"}
]},{
"title":"Contact",
"url":"/contact"
}]
```

Using the following Javascript:

```
var menu = // JSON from menu.txt

function parseNodes(nodes) {
    var ul = document.createElement('UL');
    for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        ul.appendChild(parseNode(nodes[i]));
    }
    return ul;
}
function parseNode(node) { // takes a node object and turns it into a <li>
    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    var a = ('<a href="'+node.url+'">'+node.title+'</a>');
    li.innerHTML = a;
    if(node.nodes) li.appendChild(parseNodes(node.nodes));
    return li;
}
document.getElementById('menu').appendChild(parseNodes(menu));
```

I can create the following HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about/staff">Staff</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about/location">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to do this in PHP as to be more search-engine friendly? Preferably a PHP script that I could include `menu.php` in my pages?

```
<?php

$file = "menu.txt";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

// ????

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started ;)

```
<?php
function parseNodes($nodes) {
        $ul = "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
                $ul .= parseNode($node);
        }
        $ul .= "</ul>\n";
        return $ul;
}

function parseNode($node) {
        $li = "\t<li>";
        $li .= '<a href="'.$node->url.'">'.$node->title.'</a>';
        if (isset($node->nodes)) $li .= parseNodes($node->nodes);
        $li .= "</li>\n";
        return $li;
}


$json = '[{
"title":"About",
"url":"/about",
"nodes":[
    {"title":"Staff","url":"/about/staff"},
    {"title":"Location","url":"/about/location"}
]},{
"title":"Contact",
"url":"/contact"
}]';
$nodes = json_decode($json);

$html = parseNodes($nodes);
echo $html;
```