# Loading the Select Box again on clearing the text box field

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Select box and a text box to search through the list in the select box. The Select box is getting populated from a database with PHP. What I am trying to achieve here is as soon as clear the text field; the select box should refresh. I have to reload the whole page to do that. Here is the little script that I using to search through select box.

```
function filterSelectBox(filterButton) {
    var searchValue = document.getElementById('selectFilter').value.toLowerCase();
    var selectField = document.getElementById("domainID");
    var optionsLength = selectField.options.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < optionsLength; i++) {
        if(selectField.options[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) >= 0) {
            selectField.options[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            selectField.options[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is HTML Elements associated with the code.

```
<div class="search_domains" id="search_domains">
    <input type="text"  id="selectFilter" name="selectFilter" />
    <input type="button" id="filterButton" value="Filter" onClick="filterSelectBox(this)"/>
</div>
```

and this is how I am populating the Select box,

```
<select name="domainID" id="domainID" size="15" style="width:175">
        <option>Select a Domain</option>
        <? foreach ($domains as $row) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?=$row -> id ?>"><?=$row -> domain ?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Your question does not match the code, does it?

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery.

Comment: Well, it does, why are you asking?

Comment: @AramKocharyan I am totally new to jQuery; any heads up would be great.

Comment: When and how is that function called?

Comment: The world is much better with http://jquery.com/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the function gets called when I click on the button that is with the text box.

Comment: Can you include the HTML for the elements mentioned in the question, please?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I just edited the question with html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code:

```
document.getElementById('selectFilter').onkeyup = function() {
    if(this.value.length == 0) {
        var selectField = document.getElementById("domainID");
        var optionsLength = selectField.options.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < optionsLength; i++) {
            selectField.options[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
};
```

just before the `</body>` tag in your page, and it will show all of the options when you clear the textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do here is populate the list with AJAX from that same PHP file, but have it output JSON. On loading the page, the AJAX request would load the php file, get the JSON and add the items in the list.

For refreshing when the text field is blank, you could use an onChange or onKeyUp and check the `length` of the value.

I think all this would be much simpler in jQuery or any JS framework than pure JS :)

These will help:

- http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/
- [Using jQuery, JSON and AJAX to populate a drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564333/using-jquery-json-and-ajax-to-populate-a-drop-down)
- [Populate dropdown using json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265341/populate-dropdown-using-json)
- [Populate Dropdown Menu in PHP from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874652/populate-dropdown-menu-in-php-from-json)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I added some more code to make the question clear.

Comment: @user1361350 Your problem still boils down to "I have some `<option>` elements that are hidden, how do I show them again when the text in a textbox is cleared?" You don't need **anything** mentioned in this answer to solve that - you need a `change` or `keyup` event handler that checks the length of the textbox value, and if necessary, loops through the option elements and sets their `display` property back to `block`.

Comment: +@AnthonyGrist sorry, I may have misunderstood. He said "refresh" so I assumed there was a need to repopulate the data. If it does boil down to showing and hiding, then this is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use AJAX, but for this example, it may not be necessary. It might be more efficient to just store the original contents in a Javascript array and reset it when you need to. I would actually remove the options instead of hiding them:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    var originalOptions = {<?php $echo = array(); foreach ($domains as $row) $echo[] = "\"{$row->id}\":\"{$row->domain}\""; echo implode(", ", $echo); ?>};

    function filterSelectBox(text)
    {
        var selectField = document.getElementById('domainID');
        selectField.options.length = 0;

        for (var key in originalOptions)
        {
            if (originalOptions[key].substr(0, text.length) == text)
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = key;
                option.text = originalOptions[key];
                selectField.add(option, null);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<select name="domainID" id="domainID" size="15" style="width:175">
    <?php foreach ($domains as $row) {
        echo "\t<option value=\"{$row->id}\">{$row->domain}</option>\n";
    } ?>
</select>

<input type="text" onkeyup="filterSelectBox(this.value)" />
```

Comment: He's not removing the options, only setting their `display` CSS property to `none`, so he just needs to set that back to `block` on **all** elements if the value of the text box is empty.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Yeah, I just realized that. Working on editing my answer now.